# Enabling Hibernation of Existing VM on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hibernate

I have created an EC2 VM on AWS. I have not selected the ability to Hibernate the VM during its creation. From my understanding after doing some reading, I should be able to change this setting even after its creation, but I am not able to find any reliable source regarding the procedure to follow. As an example, this [site](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-quickly-launch-encrypted-ebs-backed-ec2-instances-from-unencrypted-amis/) provides the process, but I am not able to see my VM at step 2, as indicated in that process.

Is it possible to enable the Hibernation of an existing VM?

Thank you. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> ### [Enable hibernation for an instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enabling-hibernation.html)
>
> You can't enable or disable hibernation for an instance after you
> launch it.

Comment: Thank you @John Mahowald Yes, I had seen that statement, but thought that I had also read somewhere that it was now possible and that this was perhaps outdated info. Would you know of a way to "migrate/clone" somehow my current instance so that I can make it Hibernateable somehow? I have tried to create an image starting from the instance, but this does not provide you with any option to enable hibernation on the new VM. Thanks again.